# Cant delete Docker image

Tags: docker

I want to delete a image but i get

```
Failed to remove image (b9387432d394): Error response from daemon: 
conflict: unable to delete b9387432d394 (cannot be forced) - image has
dependent child images
```

I have done this a few times but never run into a problem like this.

1. Ive run a image (doesnt really care what it was)

   ```
   $ docker run -dt ubuntu:16.04
   ```
2. Ive logged in and created a empty file

   ```
   $ docker exec -it <my_container_id>
   ```
3. Ive logged out and create a new image with the commit command

   ```
   $ exit
   $ docker commit -m "some change" <container_id> <new_image_name>
   ```
4. Ive removed all containers

   ```
   $ docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
   ```
5. Ive verified that all containers are gone and my image is in the list

   ```
   $ docker ps 
     // received a empty list
   $ docker images
     // received a list with the base and my new image
   ```
6. Ive tried to remove the base image

   ```
   $ docker rmi -f <image_id>
   ```

But i received the error `Failed to remove image`

Comment: The image is probably used by another image (child). If you remove it, the child image will become unusable that why I suppose docker prevent you from delete it.

Comment: Yes, thats what the error says. But it makes no sense at all. I ve done this a few times and it worked. How could my new image depend on the other? They both have the same size.

Comment: They are different since there is an empty file in the second one. Did you update your OS or docker version ? It perhaps added some additional verification.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the untagged images using

```
docker rmi $(docker images -aq -f dangling=true)
```